# angular failing in mock data testing with error 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a dummy service to return some dummy data, then get it called by a component ts file.  But i got error like 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'.

Found a few posts with similar error,but still can not figure out how to correct mine.

**upload.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InvalidSOEIDModel } from '../Uploadmodel/uploadmodel'
import {of} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
  ReturnData: Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]>;

 UploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]> {
    const ReturnData = { data:
      [
      {
        SOEID: "AAAAA"
      },
      {
        SOEID: "BBBBB"
      }
    ]
  };
 
    return this.ReturnData;
  }
}
```

**file-load-init.component.ts:**

```
import { BaseComponent } from '../../common/scripts/baseComponent';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UploadService } from '../UploadService/upload.service';
import { InvalidSOEIDModel } from '../Uploadmodel/uploadmodel';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-load-init',
  templateUrl: './file-load-init.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-load-init.component.css']
})
export class FileLoadInitComponent implements OnInit {
  
  InvalidSOEIDModel:InvalidSOEIDModel[];
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private UploadService: UploadService,) {}


  OnUpload(){
    
  this.GetSOEIDVerifyData();
  };


  private   GetSOEIDVerifyData(){  
    this.UploadService.UploadDataReturn()
     .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
          console.log(res);
        }
     )}
```

Can someone please help to check? I'm new to angular.

Comment: You're importing `of` from RxJS, but you're not using it... So `ReturnData` is not an observable.

Comment: yeah i was trying to use of at some point, but did not work, so i removed of and used return data. @H3AR7B3A7. Still getting error, and I posted under your answer. can you please help to check agaiin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RxJS Operator: of()

To return an observable you can use the RxJS operator `of`.

Change this in your service this :

```js
uploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]> {
  return of([
    {
      SOEID: "AAAAA"
    },
    {
      SOEID: "BBBBB"
    }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InvalidSOEIDModel } from '../Uploadmodel/uploadmodel';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

 UploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]> {
  return of([
      {
        SOEID: "AAAAA"
      },
      {
        SOEID: "BBBBB"
      }
    ]};
  }
}

Thanks!! I am getting new error 'src/app/roaster-load/UploadService/upload.service.ts:17:6 - error TS1005: ',' expected.'

Comment: @ella Either you have some syntax error in the code, or you have a version mismatch with your typescript library. If you drop your code in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) I can help you look for it.

Comment: unfortunately this is company code so I can not put the whole package there.

Comment: oh I was missing ')' !! thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hi, what if i need to add a array name for the json text? this format doesnt seem right.  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InvalidSOEIDModel } from '../Uploadmodel/uploadmodel';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

 UploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]> {
  return of ( { "Employee": [
      {
        SOEID: "AAAAA"
      },
      {
        SOEID: "BBBBB"
      }
    ]}; )  
}
}